# WPF Behavior + Storyboard animation = AssociatedObject is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Fellow WPF users,

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around a problem related to WPF Blend behaviors. I've found a behavior I'd like to use in a WPF application, but the code was originally written for Silverlight some time ago (http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/08/11/Silverlight-Behaviors-Triggers-and-Actions.aspx).

The problem I have is that when the animation starts and the dependency property `OffsetMediatorProperty` changes, and I get into the method `OnOffsetMediatorPropertyChanged`, the `AssociatedObject` is `null`. In addition, it also looks like all the fields are `null`.

The behavior I'm using:

```
public class MouseScrollViewer : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{
    double target = 0;
    int direction = 0;
    private Storyboard storyboard;
    private DoubleAnimation animation;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        CreateStoryBoard();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += AssociatedObject_MouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_MouseWheel;
        storyboard = null;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Animate(-Math.Sign(e.Delta) * ScrollAmount))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private bool Animate(double offset)
    {
        storyboard.Pause();

        if (Math.Sign(offset) != direction)
        {
            target = AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset;
            direction = Math.Sign(offset);
        }

        target += offset;
        target = Math.Max(Math.Min(target, AssociatedObject.ScrollableHeight), 0);

        animation.To = target;
        animation.From = AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset;

        if (animation.From != animation.To)
        {
            storyboard.Begin();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void CreateStoryBoard()
    {
        storyboard = new Storyboard();
        animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5),
            EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OffsetMediatorProperty));

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Completed += (s, e) => { direction = 0; };
    }

    internal double OffsetMediator
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(OffsetMediatorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OffsetMediatorProperty, value); }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetMediatorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OffsetMediator", typeof(double), typeof(MouseScrollViewer), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnOffsetMediatorPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnOffsetMediatorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseScrollViewer msv = d as MouseScrollViewer;
        if (msv != null && msv.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            msv.AssociatedObject.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    public double ScrollAmount
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollAmountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollAmountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollAmountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollAmount", typeof(double), typeof(MouseScrollViewer), new PropertyMetadata(50.0));
}
```

Usage:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MouseScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"                              
                      FontSize="32">

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

It looks like the behavior works in the Silverlight demo, but not in a WPF application. I really hope some of you are able to explain me why this happens, and hopefully help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Put breakpoint on method `OnAttached()` and see if ever gets called. If yes what's the value of AsscoiatedObject in that case. And from where you are setting value for DP `OffsetMediator`?

Comment: Yes, the `OnAttached()` method is indeed called. The value of the Associated object is the instance of my scrollviewer. With regards to the DP, this is set via the Storyboard animation, which is set up in the `CreateStoryBoard()` method in the statement `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OffsetMediatorProperty))`.

Comment: I should add, that if I set the DP directly (for example in the Animate() method), the AssociatedObject is not null. So I suspect that the problem is somehow related to the way it is set via the animation.

Comment: Oh, got it. Please see the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When storyboard is run using `Begin()`, it internally tries to *access freezable animation object which in your case is instance object of class `MouseScrollViewer` and hence it ends up cloning an instance of animation and eventually your MosueScrollViewer*.

So, actual issue is ***AssociatedObject is null because animation is done on another instance of MouseScrollViewer and not on your actual instance***.

---

There are two workarounds for this:

First call `animation.Freeze()` on animation object so that new instance is not created but issue with this approach is it will work first time only and second time it will fail with that ***freeze objects properties can't be modified***.

---

Second workaround would be to, you don't need storyboard at all when you need animation from code. You can ***directly do animation on your current instance***. Look below for the changes you need to make to do that:

**First** of all remove the `storyboard` completely from your code.

**Second** modify `CreateStoryBoard()` to `CreateAnimation()`:

```
private void CreateAnimation()
{
   animation = new DoubleAnimation
   {
      Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5),
      EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
   };

   Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new 
                               PropertyPath(OffsetMediatorProperty));

   animation.Completed += (s, e) => { direction = 0; };
}
```

and `Animate()` method should go like this:

```
private bool Animate(double offset)
{
   if (Math.Sign(offset) != direction)
   {
      target = AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset;
      direction = Math.Sign(offset);
   }

   target += offset;
   target = Math.Max(Math.Min(target, AssociatedObject.ScrollableHeight), 0);

   animation.To = target;
   animation.From = AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset;

   if (animation.From != animation.To)
   {
      this.BeginAnimation(OffsetMediatorProperty, animation); <-- HERE
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```